# Unexpected behavior of 'grep'

Tags: bash, unix, grep

Can someone please explain the behavior of **grep** for the below case:

```
$ grep <html> foo
$ bash: html: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Dont know why the question is not appearing properly after posting, the command i am facing problem is -
$ grep <html> file1
bash: html: No such file or directory
$

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `<` and `>` inside bash.

- Use a **backslash** to escape a single character
- Use **single quotes** to escape multiple characters

**Correct syntax:**

```
grep '<html>' myfile
grep \<html\> myfile
```

**Further information:**

`<` and `>` are used for [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). `<` accepts input and `>` redirects your output. Thus, `grep <html> foo` tries to read the file named `html` and redirects the output into the file `myfile`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep <html> foo
```

is

```
$ cat html | grep > foo
```

which reads the file `html` sends it to grep and stores the result in a file called foo. See hurb's answer for an extended explanation